# RestKit & RKDynamicMapping

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data, dynamic, restkit

I need to map json to coredata with restkit. Have to map based on the field "class" depending on the fields "class" can be different filled.

For example

i have json

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "uid": "rss_001",
            "message": "messge_001",
            "class": "A",
            "promo": {
                "uid": "promo_001",
                "message": "promo_msg_001",
                "bar": "0001-0001-0001-0001"
            }
        },
        {
            "uid": "rss_002",
            "message": "messge_002",
            "class": "B",
            "user": {
                "uid": "user_002",
                "avatar": "avatar_002",
                "gender": "male",
            }
        },
    ],
    "meta": {
        "timestamp": 2009392012,
        "statusCode": 200
    }
}
```

my mapping by object-c

```
    RKEntityMapping *listMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectStore:RKAPIClient_ManagedObjectStore];
    listMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"uid"];
    [listMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"uid": @"uid",
                                                     @"message": @"message",
                                                     @"class": @"dataType",
                                                     @"likedNumber": @"likedNumber",
                                                     }];

    RKEntityMapping *promoMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Promo" inManagedObjectStore:RKAPIClient_ManagedObjectStore];
    promoMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"uid"];
    [promoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"uid": @"uid",
                                                     @"message": @"message",
                                                     @"bar": @"bar",
                                                     }];

    RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:RKAPIClient_ManagedObjectStore];
    userMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"uid"];
    [userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"uid": @"uid",
                                                     @"avatar": @"avatar",
                                                     }];

     RKDynamicMapping* dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:promoMapping whenValueOfKeyPath:@"class" isEqualTo:@"A"];
[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:userMapping whenValueOfKeyPath:@"class" isEqualTo:@"B"];


 RKResponseDescriptor *listResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:listMapping
                                           method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                      pathPattern:@"list"
                                          keyPath:@"list"



statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [RKAPIClient_ObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:listResponseDescriptor];
```

but it don't work
how to set up property dynamic mapping correctly?

Comment: Looks generally ok, what problem do you have / error do you see / log output do you get ?

Comment: i get correct mapping "List", but don't mapping "Promo" & "User" and don't mapping link "List-> Promo" & "List-> User"

Comment: I think it is not enough to set up a class dynamicMapping. ti has option of match of "class" , but how it is associated with "List" - not specified

Comment: I found out that. if use `[listMapping addRelationshipFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"subcontent" withMapping:dynamicMapping];` then in dynamicMapping receives object "list" and correctly match in "class", but it need fix mapping dictionary

Comment: example fix in promo `    [promoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"promo.uid": @"uid",
                                                     @"promo.message": @"message",
                                                     @"promo.bar": @"bar",
                                                     }];`

Comment: and the same for user `  [userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"user.uid": @"uid",
                                                     @"user.avatar": @"avatar",
                                                     }];`

Comment: **but i think - this the wrong way. must be correctly configure the relation, in order to do not change mapping**

Answer (score 0):

In swift I made this solution, rivisited for your scenario.
I hope it helps you.

```
lazy var dynamicMapping: RKDynamicMapping = { [unowned self] in
        let dynMapping = RKDynamicMapping();

        let typeAMatcher:RKObjectMappingMatcher = RKObjectMappingMatcher(keyPath: "class", expectedValue: "A", objectMapping: promoMapping);
        dynMapping.addMatcher(typeAMatcher);

        let typeBMatcher:RKObjectMappingMatcher = RKObjectMappingMatcher(keyPath: "class", expectedValue: "B", objectMapping: userMapping);
        dynMapping.addMatcher(typeBMatcher);

        return dynMapping;
    }()
```